# How to add project to Create Project Wizard in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse while creating new project, the following window opens (consider the area surrounded by red lines in the image).

[image]

From that we can select project as Java Project or as per our requirement.

Now my question is, is it possible to **add Custom Java Project** as a project template  **in select Project Wizard** ? If yes, how?

I want to create (please look the area surrounded by black lines in the image) a project having the name IoTSuiteSpecification as a default Project template in Select Project Wizard with mentioned four files and package.

For example, while creating new project, IoTSuiteSpecification is there in Select Project Wizard. Let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: @Lii. Thnx for the Edit ..

Comment: You can write a plugin which uses the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point to add to the New Project wizards, but this requires you to write all the code to create everything in the project.

Comment: No problem. I hope the edit didn't change anything in a way you don't approve of.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not provide detail about what function you want to implement. This answer will just focus on how to create a new project wizard, but not the functionality details.

In short: you need to write a plugin and install that on every Eclipse you want to have this function.

I would like to keep this answer short, so the following content assumes you have basic knowledge about Eclipse Plugin Development, and have already created a plugin project. If not, please refer to tutorials such as [Your First Plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html) or Google "Eclipse Plug-in Tutorial".

**Step 1: Create an extension for your project wizard**

1. Go to plugin.xml -> Extensions -> Add -> org.eclipse.ui.newWizards, choose the "New File Wizard" template, click next.
2. Name your Classes properly. I will call everything `NewWizard`. So the wizard class is `NewWizard`, and the wizard page class is `NewWizardPage`, etc. Do not care about the "File Extension" and "Initial File Name", we won't need them.
3. Click Finish

**Step 2: Implement the classes**

After the previous step, you will have a package containing the wizard classes you just created. It should have two classes `NewWizard` and `NewWizardPage`.

First, you need to customize NewWizardPage to provide controls for your user to specify information such as Project name, etc. Refer to `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewProjectCreationPage` for an example of how to create a new Project Wizard page.

When you gather information from user, you should do some setup of your new project. Open class `NewWizard`, and find the function `performFinish`. In this function you should create your new project and setup it such as adding project natures. `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard` is the eclipse wizard for creating a new general project. It provides a good reference for how to do these. If you have no idea, read or just copy their code.

**Step 3**

That's it! Enjoy your new project wizard!

**Examples**

As an example, you can look at my project https://github.com/harperjiang/TeXDojo. This is a plugin I wrote for Eclipse to edit and compile latex files. It contains a complete project wizard implementation in the package LaTeXEditorPlugin/src/hao.tex.dojo.latexeditor.wizards

Comment: Add the attribute project="true" to the wizard element in plugin.xml.  This causes the project type to show up in Eclipse's "New Project" dialog.